# MacOS-- The database connection via brew installation was rejected

Tags: mongodb, macos

```
MACs-MBP:~ mac$ mongod -version
db version v5.0.3
Build Info: {
    "version": "5.0.3",
    "gitVersion": "657fea5a61a74d7a79df7aff8e4bcf0bc742b748",
    "modules": [],
    "allocator": "system",
    "environment": {
        "distarch": "x86_64",
        "target_arch": "x86_64"
    }
}
MACs-MBP:~ mac$ mongo
MongoDB shell version v5.0.3
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:372:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
exiting with code 1
```

The preceding command line is displayed

how to connect the Mongodb ? thanks VERY much !

Comment: Check is `mongod` is running. Run: `sudo systemctl status mongod`

Comment: If you installed using `brew`, check what `brew services list` is showing. Is mongo running correctly?